# How to fetch correctly from server side in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'd like to fetch`/data` and serverside fetch.

But I suffered following errors.

`response.getCategory is not a function`

```
(()=>{
      const url = "/data";
            
      fetch(url)
      .then(response => {
        console.log("getCategory_main.js",response.getCategory(1));
        //displayQuiz(response,1);
      });
})();
```

when we access `/data`, serverside fetch will be functioned.

```
const API_KEY="https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1&type=multiple";
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const Quiz=require("../public/javascripts/quiz");

module.exports={
    getQuiz:function(res){
      fetch(API_KEY)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => { const quiz = new Quiz(json); 
            console.log("getCategory_model",quiz.getCategory(1));
            console.log("quiz",quiz);
            res.send(quiz);
      });
    }
};
```

I can get result

`getCategory_model History`

I should pass same data from `serverside` to `clientside`

but `method` access succeeded only in `serverside`..

What is the cause of this ? and how can I fix it ? thanks..

Comment: Well compare your use of fetch in the two places - count the `then`s, maybe and note that JSON will parse to plain objects.

Answer (score 3):

You can't send objects with live methods over the wire as JSON. That is, if your server side Quiz object has a `getCategory()` method, it *won't* have one when you send it over to the client.

You'll need to serialize it, e.g.

```
res.send({
  quiz,
  categories: [quiz.getCategory(1)],
});
```

Answer (score -1):

When you fetch data, your'e fetching data (usually as text).
When you create a new quiz with `new Quiz(json)` your'e reading the json text data and using `Quiz` to create code from the json text.

So in your first example you should get the text result, and then evaluate the result to json so that you can use `getCategory()` from Quiz

```js
const url = "/data";
fetch(url)
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then(json_text=> {
            // here you use the text and parse to JSON
         const data = JSON.parse(json_text)
            // now you can create the Quiz object
         const quiz = new Quiz(data)
         console.log("getCategory_main.js", quiz.getCategory(1));
      });
```